# Recommended n-tier architecture with EF4

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

This question has been asked everywhere millions of times, but I never found a satisfying answer, one that was specfic for my problem. So here it goes:

In my company we deal with big e-commerce web sites, and we split our applications into tiers, which are: Presentation, BLL, DAL, Application-specific-framework and Models (POCO) to hold and pass data through tiers.

To access the database we write code with the Data Application Blocks in the DAL tier. The data is mapped from the DataReader to Model objects, which in turn are passed on to the BLL and the on to the Presentation tier.

I would like to start using EF4 in these big applications, but I would like it to work in a disconnected model (I know it wasn't realy meant for that, but with a little extra effort it may be achieved).

So, what would be the best way to fit EF4 in these tiers? I mean, should I put the .edmx file in the DAL tier or in the Model tier? Should I write my own Model classes and map from an Entity Model class to one of my Model classes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been my experience, that EFx, in it's current form (version 4),  is best suited for greenfield applications.

In an established application, we used the model that EF generated for us. It was located in the data layer. This required us to reference the data layer in every layer of the application. Not ideal, but it worked.

It depends on the size of your application and it's complexity, but We used EF for the simple CRUD operations. For more complex queries we opted to keep them in the database.

Comment: So suppose I'm creating a new application. I would like to use EF4, but I would not want its models being passed around to every tier (eg. Imagine I would expose some things through a web service, then it would not be cool to pass an EF4 model to the callee). Would it be the right thing to do to have POCO models in a Model tier and have the DAL fill those before passing then on the BLL? In this case, the BLL would also pass POCO objects to the DAL and then the DAL would have to map the data in the POCO object back to an EF4 model. Is this ok? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the size and life of your application. In a smaller application I'd just use the EF generated modal. As the application grows it would be better to move those classes into a business/entity layer. In a larger application I'd start with the POCO's and leverage EF. The drawback is you lose some of the designer support.  What you are looking for is Code-First: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx. HTH